# Sqoop2 - how to integrate custom pre/post-processing code (such as encryption) when doing import

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

I've used Sqoop 1 in Hadoop to integrate custom pre-processing code when performing a Sqoop import from a relational database into HDFS.  Basically, I used the `codegen` command to create the object-relational mapping class, and then modified that class source code to embed my custom pre-processing code.  Through this approach, I was able to modify the `readFields()` method to process the field values (in this case, by encrypting sensitive fields), when reading the fields from the JDBC result set and before setting them in the object instance.

I then used this modified ORM class file when performing the Sqoop import operation.  The end result was that certain fields in my data were encrypted by my custom code before being written into HDFS.

For example, modified ORM class:

```
public class Customer extends SqoopRecord  implements DBWritable, Writable {

...

  public void readFields(ResultSet __dbResults) throws SQLException {
    this.__cur_result_set = __dbResults;
    this.id = JdbcWritableBridge.readInteger(1, __dbResults);
    this.last_name = JdbcWritableBridge.readString(2, __dbResults);
    this.first_name = JdbcWritableBridge.readString(3, __dbResults);

    # encrypt cc (credit card) field, before setting value in object
    this.cc = encrypt(JdbcWritableBridge.readString(4, __dbResults));
  }

...
}
```

This approach works fine in Sqoop 1.

But I don't see any way to integrate such custom pre-processing code in Sqoop 2.  There is no `codegen` option in Sqoop2. Is there a UDF or other custom connector approach that can be used in Sqoop 2, to process fields during the Sqoop import job?  If so, can you point me at some examples or docs showing how that works in Sqoop 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sqoop 2 is not doing any code generation and as a result there is no "codegen" tool or a way how to plug-in your own code. We are thinking about introducing a simple transform phase where similar functionality would be possible, but such facilities are not yet available in Sqoop 2.